# Intellij text is not visible

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I have a problems with my intellij, text is not visible, I create a new user, change themes, switch from gnome3 to cinnamon, and I still have the same problem. That's my screen :
[image]

I will be gratefull for any help.

Comment: I have the same problem with other soft written in java (Jedit) http://tinypic.com/r/28c3trl/8

Comment: At now I used this on root : export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=setting' .And the problem is dissapeared, but I don't want to develop on root ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Android Studio on archlinux.
Tried to reinstall, reinstall xfce4, install mate - nothing was working.

Since I had the same problem on two different machines, I went through the pacman updates. 
Fortunately a downgrade from openjdk/openjre7.u60 to 7.u55 did the trick, and now everything is working fine